# How to invoke method of dynamic object using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, clearscript

I've got `dynamic` object which contains some `execute` function generated by `V8ScriptEngine`. I need to execute this method with parameters which was specified in `Dictionary` object. I tried this approach:

```
private dynamic InvokeMethod(dynamic scriptObject, Dictionary<string, string> inpuValues)
{
        dynamic result;
        ((DynamicObject) scriptObject).TryInvoke(scriptObject.execute, inpuValues.Values.ToArray(), out result);
        return result;
}
```

but it throws

> TypeError: Method or property not found

I also tried `scriptObject.GetType().GetMethod("execute").Invoke` with the same result
But if i try to execute it manually (e.g `scriptObject.execute(1,2)`) it will return valid result. How can i invoke this method dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about going through [`IReflect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.ireflect(v=vs.110).aspx)?

```
var result = ((IReflect)scriptObject).InvokeMember(
    "execute",
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, null,
    inpuValues.Values.Cast<object>().ToArray(),
    null, null, null);
```